# How to render 3d model (GLB or STL format) from server in angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, three.js, 3d-model, angular15

In my project , The admin can upload 3D models of products in glb or stl format to the Firebase FireStorage. I want them to render in my project using the link to the file that I get from the Firebase FireStorage.

I'm using angular-stl-model-viewer library, when i use a file present in my local pc in assets folder it works fine.
Here is the code

```
<stl-model-viewer style="width: 500px;height: 500px;"  [stlModels]="['assets/exapmle.stl']"></stl-model-viewer>
```

but when I replace the path with url of file from server it doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
<stl-model-viewer style="width: 500px;height: 500px;"  [stlModels]="['https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/virtualdigi-expo.appspot.com/o/industrialists%2F%2B%20poly.stl?alt=media&token=097fe500-fbfa-4682-a035-9d1cd14e53ed']"></stl-model-viewer>
```

kindly, suggest the solution or any other library or  any better approach.
thanks